# Grouping rows in ranges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query, gaps-and-islands

Let's say I have the following (contrived) table of monitoring data:

```
RowID       DateStamp            Success         Error
-----       -----------------    -------         -----------
1001        5/24/2019 11:23am    1               None 
1004        5/24/2019 11:24am    1               None 
1005        5/24/2019 11:25am    1               None 
1009        5/24/2019 11:26am    0               SQL Timeout
1018        5/24/2019 11:27am    0               SQL Timeout 
1019        5/24/2019 11:28am    1               None 
1026        5/24/2019 11:29am    1               None 
1035        5/24/2019 11:30am    0               Planned Maintenance
1100        5/24/2019 11:31am    0               Planned Maintenance
1111        5/24/2019 11:32am    1               None
```

I'd like to group rows with the same status and error, but *only if they fall next to each other in sequence* by date or by ID (ID will be ordered correctly, but is not guaranteed to be sequential), as follows:

```
Starting             Ending               Polls  Success   Error
-----------------    -----------------    -----  -------   -----------
5/24/2019 11:23am    5/24/2019 11:25am    3      1         None
5/24/2019 11:26am    5/24/2019 11:27am    2      0         SQL Timeout
5/24/2019 11:28am    5/24/2019 11:29am    2      1         None
5/24/2019 11:30am    5/24/2019 11:31am    2      0         Planned Maintenance
5/24/2019 11:32am    5/24/2019 11:32am    1      1         None
```

A simple `GROUP BY` doesn't work:

```
SELECT MIN(DateStamp) as Starting, MAX(DateStamp) as Ending, 
      Count(*) as Polls, Success, Error
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Success, Error
ORDER BY Starting
```

Since that combines all rows with the same status/error, regardless of when they occur:

```
Starting             Ending               Polls  Success   Error
-----------------    -----------------    -----  -------   -----------
5/24/2019 11:23am    5/24/2019 11:32am    6      1         None
5/24/2019 11:26am    5/24/2019 11:27am    2      0         SQL Timeout
5/24/2019 11:30am    5/24/2019 11:31am    2      0         Planned Maintenance
```

Is there an easy way to do this in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to identify the islands is using the `LAG` analytic function and the `SUM()` window aggregate function:

```
WITH
  sentinels AS
  (
    SELECT
      DateStamp,
      Success,
      Error,
      Grp = CASE
              WHEN Success = LAG(Success) OVER (ORDER BY DateStamp ASC)
               AND Error   = LAG(Error  ) OVER (ORDER BY DateStamp ASC)
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
            END
    FROM
      dbo.myTable
  ),
  fullyMarked AS
  (
    SELECT
      DateStamp,
      Success,
      Error,
      Grp = SUM(Grp) OVER (ORDER BY DateStamp ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM
      sentinels
  )
SELECT
  Starting  = MIN(DateStamp),
  Ending    = MAX(DateStamp),
  Polls     = COUNT(*),
  Success,
  Error
FROM
  fullyMarked
GROUP BY
  Success,
  Error,
  Grp
ORDER BY
  Starting ASC
;
```

The `sentinels` CTE marks the first row of each island with a 1 and the others with a 0:

```
RowID  DateStamp          Success  Error                Grp
-----  -----------------  -------  -------------------  ---
1001   5/24/2019 11:23am  1        None                 1
1004   5/24/2019 11:24am  1        None                 0
1005   5/24/2019 11:25am  1        None                 0
1009   5/24/2019 11:26am  0        SQL Timeout          1
1018   5/24/2019 11:27am  0        SQL Timeout          0
1019   5/24/2019 11:28am  1        None                 1
1026   5/24/2019 11:29am  1        None                 0
1035   5/24/2019 11:30am  0        Planned Maintenance  1
1100   5/24/2019 11:31am  0        Planned Maintenance  0
1111   5/24/2019 11:32am  1        None                 1
```

The `fullyMarked` CTE takes the output of `sentinels` and calculates the running total of the `Grp` column, thus effectively assigning a unique ID to each island:

```
RowID  DateStamp          Success  Error                Grp
-----  -----------------  -------  -------------------  ---
1001   5/24/2019 11:23am  1        None                 1    -- 1
1004   5/24/2019 11:24am  1        None                 1    -- 1+0
1005   5/24/2019 11:25am  1        None                 1    -- 1+0+0
1009   5/24/2019 11:26am  0        SQL Timeout          2    -- 1+0+0+1
1018   5/24/2019 11:27am  0        SQL Timeout          2    -- 1+0+0+1+0
1019   5/24/2019 11:28am  1        None                 3    -- 1+0+0+1+0+1
1026   5/24/2019 11:29am  1        None                 3    -- 1+0+0+1+0+1+0
1035   5/24/2019 11:30am  0        Planned Maintenance  4    -- 1+0+0+1+0+1+0+1
1100   5/24/2019 11:31am  0        Planned Maintenance  4    -- 1+0+0+1+0+1+0+1+0
1111   5/24/2019 11:32am  1        None                 5    -- 1+0+0+1+0+1+0+1+0+1
```

The final step is to just group by `Success, Error, Grp` and aggregate data of other columns as required, which gives you the expected result.

You can use this [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9a1b9af226c6d9d16753f85e550ae4ae) at [image: dbfiddle logo]db<>fiddle.uk for playing with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is one example of creating groups with the use of `ROW_NUMBER()`**

```
;WITH CTE_GROUP AS (
  SELECT 
  Success, 
  Error,
  DateStamp,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Success, Error ORDER BY DateStamp)
      - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateStamp) as SuccesErrorDateStamp,
FROM dbo.myTable
)
SELECT MIN(DateStamp) as Starting, MAX(DateStamp) as Ending, 
      Count(*) as Polls, Success, Error
FROM CTE_GROUP
GROUP BY Success, Error,SuccesErrorDateStamp
ORDER BY Starting;
```

**Resulting in**

```
Starting                    Ending                      Polls   Success Error
2019-05-24 11:23:00.0000000 2019-05-24 11:25:00.0000000 3       1       None
2019-05-24 11:26:00.0000000 2019-05-24 11:27:00.0000000 2       0       SQL Timeout
2019-05-24 11:28:00.0000000 2019-05-24 11:29:00.0000000 2       1       None
2019-05-24 11:30:00.0000000 2019-05-24 11:31:00.0000000 2       0       Planned Maintenance
2019-05-24 11:32:00.0000000 2019-05-24 11:32:00.0000000 1       1       None
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a16f03ae6612917c4f6e4106be9db0f3)

*Thanks [@AndriyM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m) for pointing out that I only need one `ROW_NUMBER()` column*